# The best way to show loader message during model.list loading

Tags: promise, canjs, canjs-model

I created a simple MVC application with canjs for an users list, by using can.Model.List.
Since my request could take more than 5 second, I would add in the view a little preload message/image during the loading.

i.e. I would something like this (I'm using mustache)

```
var users = new Users.List({});
element.html(can.view('myView', users);
```

with this template:

```
{{#if loading}}
   <p>Loading, please wait...</p>
{{else}}
   <ul>
      {{#each this}}
         <li>User {{ name }} {{ surname }}</li>
      {{/each}}
   </ul>
{{/if}}
</ul>
```

I can solve by having a new observable variable, but I think there's a better way to direct manage this deferred data inside the view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [list promise plugin](http://canjs.com/docs/can.List.plugins.promise.html) to show a loading indicator while a Deferred is being resolved:

```
var users = new Users.List();
users.replace(Users.findAll());
element.html(can.view('myView', { users: users });
```

This will even allow you to show loading error messages:

```
{{#if users.isPending}}
   <p>Loading, please wait...</p>
{{else}}
  {{#if users.isResolved}}
   <ul>
      {{#each users}}
         <li>User {{ name }} {{ surname }}</li>
      {{/each}}
   </ul>
   {{else}}
   There was an error loading the user list.
   {{/if}}
{{/if}}
</ul>
```